# How to make a bar across lambda?

Tags: symbols

If I want to make a bar across `h` I just use `\hbar`. But what shall I do if I want to make a line across `\lambda` like on the picture?

[image: lambda]

PS: I use the the book document class.

Comment: oh thansk :-) .. sorry, I didn't see that post - and I have really used google but couldn't find anything. Thansk!